# pass a query to row_to_json function inside a store procedure in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to write a store procedure where I pass a query into a stored procedure which will internally call the row_to_json function. We have multiple DBMS (Oracle, SQL Server & postgres) and want to write a generic procedure which will act as a wrapper for the json handling function.

I am looking at something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proj.sql_row_to_json(sql_t text)
 RETURNS json
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
  with t as (select sql_t )
  select row_to_json(t) from t;
$function$
```

I would call function in my application as

`select SQL_ROW_TO_JSON('<sql query>')` -> which should work across different databases

But the above procedure gives me the below result instead of the actual data.

```
select SQL_ROW_TO_JSON('SELECT id,name FROM emp')

{"sql_t":"SELECT id,name FROM emp"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use plpgsql and [dynamic sql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

```
create or replace function sql_row_to_json(sql_t text)
returns json language plpgsql as $function$
declare rslt json;
begin
    execute
        format($ex$
            select json_agg(row_to_json(t)) 
            from (%s) t
        $ex$, sql_t)
    into rslt;
    return rslt;
end;
$function$;

select sql_row_to_json('select 1 as id, ''abcd'' as value');

     sql_row_to_json     
-------------------------
 {"id":1,"value":"abcd"}
(1 row)
```

Note that the function is prone to [SQL-injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: See the edited answer. With `json_agg()` added the function can aggregate more than one row of the result.